# Visual C# to Visual C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I need to use dlls, headers and functions from a Visual C# project in  a Visual C++ project.

I tried to add the dlls via "Add References" but I keep getting this error...

Caching metadata information for e:\linha_3_os179\indutron_opc\treiberdlls\elabo.devices.g_series.deviceplugin.dll

Any suggetions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to expose the c# code as COM objects and then use COM from c to call them